# Cannot ping interface although in same subnet? Why? Debug ip packet gives encapsulation error

Tags: packet-tracer, icmp

I have the following setup:

From Laptop Mgmt2 (bottom right) I want to ping Se/0/0/0 on R1. I can only ping S0/0/0 on ISP router, which is in the same subnet.

If I enable debug ip packet on isp router I receive the following error

IP: s=209.165.240.10 (Serial0/0/1), d=209.165.240.2 (Serial0/0/0), len 296, encapsulation failed. How can I fix this?

ISP router

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2054 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname ISP1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX15241K07-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 209.165.241.1 255.255.255.240
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 ipv6 address FE80::B link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC0A::1/64
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 209.165.240.1 255.255.255.248
 ip access-group NO_PRIVATE in
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC05::2/64
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 ip address 209.165.240.9 255.255.255.248
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC09::1/64
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 ip address 209.170.240.1 255.255.255.252
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC08::2/64
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 1.0.0.0 255.255.255.248 Serial0/0/0 
ip route 1.0.0.0 255.255.255.248 Serial0/1/1 250
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/1/1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
ipv6 route ::/0 Serial0/1/1
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC00::/64 Serial0/0/0
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64 Serial0/0/0
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC02::/64 Serial0/0/0
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC03::/64 Serial0/0/0
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC04::/64 Serial0/0/0
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC07::/64 Serial0/1/1
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC0B::/64 Serial0/0/1
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC0C::/64 Serial0/0/1
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC00::/64 Serial0/1/1 25
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC01::/64 Serial0/1/1 25
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC02::/64 Serial0/1/1 25
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC03::/64 Serial0/1/1 25
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC04::/64 Serial0/1/1 25
!
ip access-list extended NO_PRIVATE
 deny ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 deny ip 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 any
 deny ip 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip any any
!
no cdp run
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

R1

```
    Current configuration : 4924 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
enable password class
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
username Administrator password 0 Pasw0rd+
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524HE77-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 10.15.246.1 255.255.255.0
 mtu 1476
 tunnel source Serial0/0/0
 tunnel destination 209.165.240.10
!
!
interface Tunnel1
 no ip address
 mtu 1476
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC0D::1/64
 tunnel source Serial0/0/0
 tunnel destination 209.165.240.10
 tunnel mode ipv6ip
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.25
 encapsulation dot1Q 25
 ip address 1.0.0.4 255.255.255.248
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::5 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC04::1/64
 standby 25 ip 1.0.0.1
 standby 25 priority 105
 standby 25 preempt
 standby 25 track Serial0/0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.240
 encapsulation dot1Q 240
 ip address 10.15.240.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group MITARBEITER in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC00::1/64
 standby 240 ip 10.15.240.1
 standby 240 priority 105
 standby 240 preempt
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.241
 encapsulation dot1Q 241
 ip address 10.15.241.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC01::1/64
 standby 241 ip 10.15.241.1
 standby 241 priority 105
 standby 241 preempt
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.242
 encapsulation dot1Q 242
 ip address 10.15.242.9 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::3 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC02::1/64
 standby 242 ip 10.15.242.1
 standby 242 priority 105
 standby 242 preempt
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.243
 encapsulation dot1Q 243
 ip address 10.15.243.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip access-group GAESTE in
 ip nat inside
 ipv6 address FE80::4 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC03::1/64
 standby 243 ip 10.15.243.1
 standby 243 priority 105
 standby 243 preempt
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.244
 encapsulation dot1Q 244
 ip address 10.15.244.9 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.15.242.13
 ip nat inside
 standby 244 ip 10.15.244.1
 standby 244 priority 105
 standby 244 preempt
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 ip address 209.165.240.2 255.255.255.248
 ip access-group ESTABLISHED in
 ip nat outside
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:6:BC05::1/64
!
interface Serial0/0/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip nat inside source list NAT interface Serial0/0/0 overload
ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0 
ip route 10.15.247.0 255.255.255.0 10.15.246.2 
ip route 10.15.245.0 255.255.255.0 10.15.246.2 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
ipv6 route ::/0 Serial0/0/0
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC0B::/64 2001:DB8:6:BC0D::2
ipv6 route 2001:DB8:6:BC0C::/64 2001:DB8:6:BC0D::2
!
ip access-list extended NAT
 permit ip 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 1.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended MITARBEITER
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 permit udp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.13 eq domain
 permit tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.13 eq domain
 permit icmp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.13 echo
 permit tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.14 eq 20
 permit tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.14 eq ftp
 deny tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 10.15.240.0 0.0.5.255 eq www
 deny tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 10.15.240.0 0.0.5.255 eq 443
 permit tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any eq www
 permit tcp 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 443
ip access-list extended GAESTE
 permit udp host 0.0.0.0 eq bootpc host 255.255.255.255 eq bootps
 permit udp 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.13 eq domain
 permit tcp 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.15.242.13 eq domain
 deny tcp 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 10.15.240.0 0.0.5.255 eq www
 deny tcp 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 10.15.240.0 0.0.5.255 eq 443
 permit tcp 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any eq www
 permit tcp 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 any eq 443
ip access-list extended ESTABLISHED
 permit icmp any any echo
 permit icmp any any echo-reply
 permit udp any any eq domain
 permit tcp any any eq domain
 permit tcp any host 1.0.0.3 eq 443
 permit tcp any 1.0.0.0 0.0.0.4 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.240.0 0.0.0.255 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.241.0 0.0.0.255 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.242.0 0.0.0.255 established
 permit tcp any 10.15.243.0 0.0.0.255 established
!
no cdp run
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

[image: Setup]

Comment: Please do not - ever - use public IP addresses that you don't own. Also, please indicate the ISP router and which interface leads where. It's good practice to name interfaces.